Left-align work in latex but not in Sphinx
Left-align the equation in latex.
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\begin{document} 
\begin{flalign*} 
    a &= b + c &\\ 
    d &= e + f + g &\\ 
    h &= i - j &
\end{flalign*} 

Now i want to make the equation left align in sphinx:
.. math::

    \begin{flalign*} 
      a &= b + c &\\ 
      d &= e + f + g &\\ 
      h &= i - j &
   \end{flalign*} 

I find it can't make the equation align left.To edit the conf.py file in sphinx project can take effect:
mathjax3_config = {'chtml': {'displayAlign': 'left'}}

But it will make every equation in the sphinx left aligned,how can just make the editing equation left align ,instead of all?

mathjax only emulates a subset of the latex syntax, it does not actually use latex.

Using MathJax I think you're supposed to give the specific class to that .. math:: directive and then target that :class: by adding a custom CSS rule.
